# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "130 PHP"

Tags: invalid-characters

I dont know how to solve this problem

i cant find my error in codes

pls help me solve it :( thanks!

```
 private void loadListFood() {
    cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cart,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    int total = 0;
    for(Order order:cart)
        total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));


}
```

i am being redirected to 
**total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));**

here is my adapter codes

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder>{
    private List<Order> listData = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context context;

    public CartAdapter(List<Order> cart, Cart cart1)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlayout,parent,false);
        return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound(""+listData.get(position).getQuantity(), Color.RED);
        holder.img_cart_count.setImageDrawable(drawable);


        int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
        holder.txt_price.setText(price);
        holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JavaDoc: The method `Integer.parseInt(String s)` throws a `NumberFormatException`

> if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

That means, method `order.getPrice()` or `order.getQuantity()` returns `"130 PHP"` which is not a valid `Integer`.

Your real problem might be: Why the method returns a `String` and not `Integer` because you have to parse your `String` now. Pretty error prone and bad practice.

If your GUI element (or whatever) does not fit with `Integer`, at least remove your "PHP" out of the input field and you might be able to parse your `String` without manipulate it with some String helper methods.

Comment: i removed the PHP from the prices of my items from my database but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Verify that your method `order.getPrice()` return `"130"` and not something like `"130 "`. `"130"` is parsable, `"130 "` is not.

Comment: How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: [Debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) your App or `System.out.println()` your variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class  CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    , View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    public TextView txt_cart_name,txt_price;
    public ImageView img_cart_count;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public void setTxt_cart_name(TextView txt_cart_name) {
        this.txt_cart_name = txt_cart_name;
    }

    public CartViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txt_cart_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_name);
        txt_price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_Price);
        img_cart_count = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_count);

        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {

        contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Selecione uma Ação");
        contextMenu.add(0,0,getAdapterPosition(),Common.DELETE);
    }
}

public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder> {

    private List<Order> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public CartAdapter(List<Order> listData, Context context) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_layout,parent,false);
        return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound(""+listData.get(position).getQuantity(), Color.BLUE);
        holder.img_cart_count.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        Locale locale = new Locale("pt","BR");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
        holder.txt_price.setText(fmt.format(price));

        holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }
}
```